# Adding a loop within python sub-process

Tags: python, for-loop, terminal, subprocess, nested-loops

I need some help! I have a script that loops through all of the files in a directory and runs a subprocess to use a command line tool (fimo) on each file. Fimo is a tool used to search genetic sequences for specific subsequences, or motifs. As my code exists now, only 1 motif is being searched for ("/home/MA0074.1.meme").

I would like to change this code so that it loops through more than 1 motif. I am not sure how to add a loop into the subprocess, or how a variable within a subprocess might work (something like another {f}?), and I'm having trouble finding information.

Additional motifs could be like:

```
"/home/MA0796.1.meme"
"/home/MA0113.3.meme"
```

etc.

Here's the code as it exists now:

```
import subprocess
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os
import os.path

os.chdir("/home/meme/src")
i = 0

path_of_the_directory= "/home/fastas_no_canonical"
for filename in os.listdir(path_of_the_directory):
    f = os.path.join(path_of_the_directory,filename)
    print(filename)
    i= i+1
    placeHolder = str(os.path.basename(filename))
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        result = subprocess.run(f'./fimo --oc "/home/fimos/%s" --verbosity 1 --thresh 1.0E-4 "/home/MA0074.1.meme" "{f}"'%(placeHolder), shell=True)
        print(f)
```

EDIT:
I have added a second for loop to my code and fixed the f-strings like so:

```
i = 0

path_of_the_directory= "/home/fastas_no_canonical"
path_of_memes= "/home/test_memes"
for filename in os.listdir(path_of_the_directory):
    for meme in os.listdir(path_of_memes):
        f = os.path.join(path_of_the_directory,filename)
        m = os.path.join(path_of_memes,meme)
        i= i+1
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            result = subprocess.run(f'./fimo --oc "/home/test_memes/junk/{filename}/{meme}" --verbosity 1 --thresh 1.0E-4 "{m}" "{f}"', shell=True)
            print(f)
            print(m)
```

It is working, but only for the first file. The output contains a folder with data for each motif search for the first input file, but then freezes. I checked with print(f) and print(m) that the file names are right, so this is how I can tell that it freezes after the first file.

Does anyone see an error in my loop that might be causing this? Do I need another iterator?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how to add a loop into the subprocess, or how a variable within a subprocess might work (something like another {f}?)

You have some of the right idea here, but this is the incorrect way to think about it. You don't create a variable "within a subprocess".  Instead, you have a variable in your python code that stores the path to a motif. You add the name in that variable to the string which you pass to `subprocess.run()`. You can even make a loop that iterates over a list of these paths. In pseudocode it might look something like this:

```
for each dna sequence file
   for each motif
       search the dna sequence for the motif
```

As a general rule, describing the steps to solve a problem in words in this way is a great place to start. I'll leave it to the reader to translate this into code.

On a side note, either use `f''` or `''%()`, but not both.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have edited my post and added a second for loop for the motif, but I'm not sure how to code the variable for the motifs. I don't know the difference between f '' or ''%(), I think I have both in this code because I was having trouble keeping unique names in the file ouputs.

Comment: @LauraMorgan I suggest you read about f-strings in python. These are a newer way to do what `%` used to be used for.

Comment: check it out! I read about f strings and believe I fixed them. Thanks for the direction. The script is working for the first file, but isn't looping through files like it should. Do you see why this might be happening?

Comment: @LauraMorgan Glad to hear you are making progress. I suggest reading [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging the current version to figure out why it isn't working the way you want.